# Rails ActiveRelation Sub Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-relation

Im new to rails and have a question about accessing relations of relations in ActiveRecord.

Consider this psuedo code:

```
class Organisation
has_many: :projects

class Project
has_many: :tests

class Test
belongs_to: project
```

Effectively 3 levels. I need to access the Tests for a particular Organisation, although I can only go as deep as the Projects.

ie

```
@organisation = Organisation.find(params[:id], :include => [:projects])
```

Really, what I need to do would be something like

```
@organisation.projects.scripts.all
```

but from what im reading, thats not possible.  So, whats the solution for this?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
@organisation = Organization.includes(:projects => :tests).find(params[:id])
@organization.projects.collect(&:tests)
```

That will eagerly load one organization and all its projects and tests, and then it'll collect all tests for all projects related to that organization.